# Find a character and insert line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How might I go about finding a specific character and inserting a line break using jQuery?

The character I need to find is a hyphen - and its always within a product title on an ecommerce site and takes the following format:

> This is a title - This is the colour

How can I find the dash for every product title and insert a line break to for the colour name on to a separate line?

The exact HTML markup I'm using is as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="product c-3">
    <div class="product-thumb">
        <!-- Other code is in here / Removed for brevity -->
        <div class="product-title">
           This is a title - This is the colour
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `replace` to find a `-` in the element's HTML and replace it with `-<br />`. Try this:

```
$('.product-title').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace('-', '-<br />');
});
```

You can replace with simply `'<br />'` if you want to remove the hyphen completely.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ow4c9yu7/)

*Update*: This can now be made even more succinct by using an arrow function:

```
$('.product-title').html((i, v) => v.replace('-', '-<br />'));
```

Comment: `^1` You nailed it bro!

Comment: what is "i" in funciton(i,v)?

Comment: @Alex the index of the element in the iteration: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.product-title').each(function() {
   var self = $(this);
   self.html(self.html().replace(/-/, '-<br/>'));
});
```